# What is difference between this.PropertyName and _PropertyName?

Tags: c#, class, linq-to-sql, this, partial

as I often let `LinqToSql` generate partial entity classes, I am wondering if my practice of adding additional properties via code is correct and if there is a better way of doing the same thing? I am also wondering what is the difference between accessing the values of other properties using `this.PROPERTY_NAME` vs `_PROPERTY_NAME`?
In my web app I keep using `this.PROPERTY_NAME`, but I am wondering if that is, as I already said in opening sentence, the proper approach I should be using. Also, What is `_PROPERTY_NAME` and when do we use it?

Example:

```
public partial class User
{
    public bool IsThisProper {
        get{
            return this.SomeIntProperty == 10; // I usually use this
        }  
    }

    public bool WhenToUseThisApproach {
        get{
            return _SomeIntProperty == 10; // What is this in comparison to above?
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Underscore is one way to avoid writing "this".  It's a shorthand way of saying, this is an entity value.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc An underscore is just another character that is valid in an identities name.  It's simply convention that it's used as a prefix to indicate a private instance field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is the property, and the other is the private backing field in which that property stores it's value.  If you want to execute whatever code the property has in it's getter/setter, then use the property, if you don't, then don't.  Chances are you want to use the property, not the field, especially with setting (setting it triggers the property changed event, so about the only time to use the property is if you don't want that event raised).

Comment: Thanks for providing proper terminology. Found more info on MSDN using this.